# Rabbitmq server failed to boot

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to start my rabbitmq server using command:`sudo rabbitmq-server` on ubuntu 20.04 but it crashes.
I have absolutely no clue whatsoever as to what I should do.
Rabbitmq version: **3.8.5** erlang version: **23**

```
17:41:07.587 [error] 

17:41:07.591 [error] BOOT FAILED
BOOT FAILED
17:41:07.592 [error] ===========
===========
17:41:07.592 [error] ERROR: distribution port 25672 in use by rabbit@nadaanbaalak
ERROR: distribution port 25672 in use by rabbit@nadaanbaalak
17:41:07.592 [error] 

17:41:08.594 [error] Supervisor rabbit_prelaunch_sup had child prelaunch started with rabbit_prelaunch:run_prelaunch_first_phase() at undefined exit with reason {dist_port_already_used,25672,"rabbit","nadaanbaalak"} in context start_error
17:41:08.594 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.153.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{dist_port_already_used,25672,"rabbit","nadaanbaalak"}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}} in application_master:init/4 line 138
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{dist_port_already_used,25672,\"rabbit\",\"nadaanbaalak\"}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{dist_port_already_used,25672,"rabbit","nadaanbaalak"}}},{rabb

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. Just needed to look at the logs. killed the process at the port number "25672" and restarted the rabbitmq server.

Comment: sudo lsof -i :2562
sudo kill -9 pid